# Excel IRR: can I use it referencing a combination of cells and fixed numbers? IRR({-10,11+A2})

Tags: excel, irr

Most Excel users are probably familiar with the syntax of Excel's IRR formula: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/irr-function-64925eaa-9988-495b-b290-3ad0c163c1bc

I can use IRR using only fixed numbers, and without referencing cells, e.g.

`=IRR({-100,110})`  will return 10%. This works regardless of whether I enter it as an array formula (CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER).

However, what I cannot seem to do is using a combination of fixed numbers and cells, e.g.

```
=IRR({-100,110+a2})
```

doesn't work: regardless of whether I enter it as an array formula or not, I get the same error message:

```
we found an error with this formula.
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

`=IRR(CHOOSE({1,2},-100,110+A2))`

Answer (score 0):

If you try to do to math inside `{}`, for example `={1,2+5}` 
excel does not know what to do. 
Does also apply inside formulas.

Try to do the array as a reference i.e
`=IRR(B1:C1)`
and then do math etc inside the cells referenced.